# Create Line & Bar charts with Marquee behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, charts, materialize

I want your opinion on how to create this [materializecss admin dashboard](http://demo.geekslabs.com/materialize/v2.1/layout03/index.html) line and bar charts moving from right to left with changing timelines[image]

I have look at chartist.js and its animations, I didn't see it there. Please how I can achieve this marquee effect on the line and bar charts?

Comment: You have a lot many javascript charting frameworks, such as `chart.js`, `highcharts` etc..

Comment: The problem isn't creating the charts but adding the marquee effect (animation) on the chart. Did you open the link I attached to the post? Open it and see the marquee effect (animation) am seeking opinion for

Comment: try this https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery#basic-charts

Comment: @GreenOnyeji http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update - here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lieutenant Jim Dangle and @Karthik VU. I found their comments useful. A look at path transition of D3.js https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/ and Animating path at http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326 and also Spline updating using Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update answer this question.